# UIPageViewController Showing Wrong View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that I'm using to handle a custom Calendar I made. The calendar is a day view, so essentially, each day is the same type of view controller showing times in that day and any events that the user has.

When I swipe forward or back in the page view controller to change days, it seems to get out of sequence within about two swipes.

When each view controller is called, it is passed a date, and as soon as that view controller loads, I assign the date string to the navigation bar, and also use this date to get events from a dictionary.

Most of the time, the navigation bar text is correct (it doesn't appear to skip any days while swiping), but even if the nav text is right, it will sometimes show events from the wrong day. To test this, I created a label to print the Dictionary Key string (which I use to fetch events for a specific date), and print that key to the label to see if it matches the navigation bar title.

Oddly, both the label and the navigation bar are assigned from the same date, but will sometimes show a different string. Usually the day is offset just by one in the label, while the nav is correct.

Here's my ViewController which instantiates the UIPageViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self loadDatesArray];

    self.navigationController.title = @"Day View";

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarDayPageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    self.pageViewController.delegate = self;
    self.pageViewController.startDateForDayView = _startDateForDayView;
    self.pageViewController.hashMap = _hashMap;

    EICalendarDayContentViewController *startingVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarDayPageContentController"];
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[startingVC] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];


    NSArray *subviews = self.pageViewController.view.subviews;
    UIPageControl *thisControl = nil;
    for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
        if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
            thisControl = (UIPageControl *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i]; } }
    thisControl.hidden = true;

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height + 49);

    [self addChildViewController:_pageViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:_pageViewController.view];
    [self.pageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    _index = 250;
    _stepsBack = 0;
    _stepsForward = 0;
}



- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    _index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:_index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    _index++;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:_index];

}

- (EICalendarDayContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSDate *date = [_DateArray objectAtIndex:index];
    EICalendarDayContentViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarDayPageContentController"];
    vc.dateForView = date;
    vc.pageIndex = index;
    return vc;
}


- (void)loadDatesArray {
    _DateArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = -250; i < 250; i++) {
        NSDate *newDate = [_startDateForDayView dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*i];
        NSLog(@"Date Array = %@ atIndex = %d", newDate, i);
        [_DateArray addObject:newDate];
    }
}
```

The [self loadDatesArray] loads an array with 500 dates; 250 before and 250 after the current date.

Because of this, the _index starts at 250 (the current day) and beforeViewController calls date 249, and afterViewController calls 251, etc...

Please help.. Been stuck on this for too long.